# ElectronJS Caching Issue

Tags: node.js, electron, chromium

I am developing a desktop app using ElectronJS.  When I make changes to the main html file or any of the javascript files that it calls I am getting a cached version after running the program.

Things I have tried:

- Opening dev tools on the main electron window, clearing cache and
  clicking 'disable cache'
- Clearing cache using win.webContents.session.clearCache() in the main
  process.
- clearing node cache using npm cache clean --force

Has anyone ever experienced this?  Is there a way to disable caching during development?

Comment: The functions clearCache() and clearStorageData() on the Session object should be enough to clear the cache on load. Do you use something like `electron-compile` or `electron-forge` ? Or do you use a bundler that caches things sepreratly (like a .cache folder) ?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting `Reload` from the appropriate menu (`View` by default) or calling its keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Cmd-R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> by default) should reload any modified HTML, CSS or JavaScript files used by the renderer process...

In case it's not sufficient, selecting `Force Reload` may be necessary, provided it is available in the menu; keyboard shortcut is  <kbd>Shift-Cmd-R</kbd> or <kbd>Shift-Ctrl-R</kbd> by default.